# i want to get all related pics corresponding to the pic selected

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get all the related pics corresponding to the pic selected....
here is my view page`

```
<?php foreach($detail as $row){?>                                       
<img class="primary-image" ima="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $row->image;?>" src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $row->image;?>" alt="" />                                          
<?php }?>
```

my **control page** looks like this....

```
public function product_details($p_id)
{
    $data['active_mn']='product_details';
    $data['product']=$this->roxmodel->get_product_details($p_id);
    $data['productColor']=$this->roxmodel->get_product_color_details(null,$p_id)->result();

    $data['detail']=$this->roxmodel->get_related_image($p_id,4,0);
    var_dump($data['detail']);
    $this->load->view('product_details',$data);
}
```

my **model page** looks like this....

```
public function get_related_image($p_id,$limit,$offset)
{
    $this->db->join('category','category.id=gallery.image');
    $this->db->where('category.id',$p_id);
    $this->db->order_by('gallery.id','desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('gallery',$limit,$offset)->result();
    return $query;
}
```

my table contains shirts,thirsts,pants images and their corresponding category_ids are 10,11,12 when i choose the category_id=10 o shirt image i want to get all category_id=10 shirt images and like that

here is my table

```
id     image                category_id         
93   img1455604030.jpg       10              
94   img1455605183.jpg       11               
95   img1455616291.jpg       11                
96   img1455617201.jpg       10                
97   img1455617299.jpg       10                
98   img1455681918.jpg       13              
99   img1455681957.jpg       12
```

this is my code to view image by clicking

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/product_details/<?php echo $row->id; ?>/<?php echo $row->category_id; ?>">
```

my category table is this

```
id  category_name   parent_id
8   men             0
9   kids            0
10  T-shirts        8
11  Shirts          8
12  Jeans           8
13  Pants           8
14  Shorts          8
15  Tees            9
16  Shirts          9
17  Jeans           9
18  Pants           9
19  Shorts & Ber    9
20  Romper          9
```

my gallery table is this

```
id     image                category_id         
93   img1455604030.jpg       10              
94   img1455605183.jpg       11               
95   img1455616291.jpg       11                
96   img1455617201.jpg       10                
97   img1455617299.jpg       10                
98   img1455681918.jpg       13              
99   img1455681957.jpg       12
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This looks more like a Spec than a question.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: and iam not getting related images its showing null value

Comment: what comes in `$details` in *view*?

Comment: @riggs sorry..iam new here thats why

Comment: $details is specified in controler..

Comment: do `var_dump($details)` and see what comes

Comment: my table looks like this

Comment: when i did var_dump its comes like this array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: run last_query in model and see query then run that query in database to see result

Comment: do:`print_r($this->db->last_query())` **befor return $query;**

Comment: @PathikVejani `$this->db->last_query()`

Comment: @DavidBm oh.. yes.. i forgot it.. thanks :)

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM `gallery` JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id`=`gallery`.`image` WHERE `category_id` IS NULL ORDER BY `gallery`.`id` DESC LIMIT 4'

Comment: it comes like this..

Comment: i want to get all values of the selected category_id.if  category_id is 10 i want to get all caregory_id =10 values..if it is 11 then i should get all category_id=11 values

Comment: @MOHAMMED then run in database

Comment: There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 123

Comment: is there any error you facing

Comment: its showing like your category_id field is zero

Comment: i had added my table please see that

Comment: use Like Condition  $this->db->like('category_id','%{$id}%');

Answer (score 0):

There is error on your **Model** file in join query.

There is no relation between **category.id=gallery.image**.

It should be **category.id=gallery.category_id** as your table structure.

Try this query. It may help you.

```
public function get_related_image($id,$limit,$offset)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('gallery');
    $this->db->join('category','category.id=gallery.category_id');
    $this->db->where('category_id',$id);
    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `gallery` JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id`=`gallery`.`category_id` WHERE `category_id` = '135' LIMIT 4

Comment: here category_id value showing is id value not category_id value.the problem is category_id value is not getting

Comment: can you post your both table structure?

Comment: As your given table structure above query is correct. Run this query SELECT * FROM gallery JOIN category ON category.id=gallery.category_id WHERE category_id = '10'